# Open a particular accordion div after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am submitting some values to database through ajax and i want to reload and open a particular accordion div after ajax call.

This is what i was trying and it doesn't work=

```
    function submit(id) {
    var submitID = '#' + id + 'submit';
    var divId = '#' + id + 'myDiv';
    $.ajax({
        'url' : base_url + controller + '/add_val',
        'type' : 'POST',
        data : { var: $(submitID).val()             
        },
        'success': function (data) {
             $("#divId").html(data);
             $("#divId").load(window.location + divId);
             $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", $("#accordion div").index(divId));
         }

    });
    }
```

HTML code is here:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <?php  foreach ($divKey as $val): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $val->name; ?></h3>
    <div id="<?php echo $val->id . "myDiv"; ?>">
        <select class="s2_select" id="<?php echo $val->id . "submit"; ?>"  name="">
           <option>value 1</option>
           <option>value 2</option>
           <option>value 3</option>
        </select>
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" onClick="submit(<?php echo $val->id; ?>)">
    <ul>
    <li>....</li>
    </ul>                                           
    </div>   
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the accordion after the "load" call in the success functionality or just along side, regardless of the previous "load" call, like you have?

Comment: Its after the load call @Daved

Comment: I should have been more clear: Do you want the tab to open once the load call completes? The ".load" function supports a "success" callback that is triggered only once the load is complete, just as .AJAX supports the "success" callback.

Comment: I want to open the accordion panel which is refreshed after ajax success

Comment: At present, when it opens first panel of accordion after jax call

Comment: Your index line is reversed in that case. $("#accordion div").index("#divId")

Comment: I did but still its not working. Again the first panel is opening

Comment: Can you provide more code then to show more context to us?

Comment: i have updated the code, please check if it is helpful