# To keep the opened collapsible panel open after an AJAX refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a main page which has a partial view. The partial view is refreshed every 60 seconds and I use AJAX to load the partial view. The code for the main page and the scripts and styles are as below.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@model SampleApp1.Models.Model1

<style>
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
/* symbol for "opening" panels */
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
/* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
content: "\e113";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}

</style>

<div id="MainPage">
@Html.Partial("_PartialPage1")
</div>


<script>
window.setInterval(function () {
    loadView();
}, 60000
    );

function loadView() {
headerArray=$('#accordion').find('[aria-expanded=true]').closest('a');
bodyArray=$('#accordion').find($('.in'));
    var targetUrl = '/Home/GetIndex';
    $.ajax({
        url: targetUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        async: true,
    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
        $("#MainPage").html(partialViewResult);
jQuery.each(headerArray, function (index, item) {
    $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded=true');
    console.log($(this))
});
jQuery.each(bodyArray, function (index, item) {
    $(this).addClass('in');
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded=true');
    console.log($(this))
});

    });
}
```

The partial view is basically a set of tabs developed using collapsible panels. I am trying to store the panels that are open and then load it as open after the screen refresh.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne">
               @Model.Header1
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Model.Tab1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseTwo">
                @Model.Header2

            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Model.Tab2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseThree">
                @Model.Header3

            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Model.Tab3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My script does not seem to work and all panels are collapsed after refresh. Am i missing something? Is there another way of doing it?

EDIT: Adding the code inside the AJAX portion did not help. When I debug from the console the tabs are open until the loadView function and when the control goes back to 60,000 it seems to collapse.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30070366/4761773) is pretty similar to my question, this was also not resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loadView function like below to store the expanded panels id and then expand it again after setting html.

```
function loadView() {
var headerArray = [];
$('#accordion .in').each(function() {
    headerArray.push(this.id);
});
var targetUrl = '/Home/GetIndex';
$.ajax({
    url: targetUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    async: true,
}).done(function(partialViewResult) {
    $("#MainPage").html(partialViewResult);
    $.each(headerArray, function(index, item) {

        $("#" + item).collapse('show');
    });

});
}
```

Check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/3gYa3/1211/). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well done!! I was trying hard with the header portion instead of using the body and setting it based on which where open. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, Piggy!! :-)

Comment: Nice! To add to the answer you loose reference to your `headerArray` after html reloads hence it wasn't working. But since element Id's remain the same it works even after reload.

Answer (score 0):

Put your open tabs code inside your ajax.done method as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: targetUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    async: true,
}).done(function (partialViewResult) {
    $("#MainPage").html(partialViewResult);
    jQuery.each(headerArray, function (index, item) {
       $(this).click();
   });
});
```

Comment: I see, is your code to remove and add class works to open/close panels? Have you validated it?

Comment: This is the fiddle I based my code on. http://jsfiddle.net/rahul25890/3gYa3/1209/

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think a simple click should do your job

Comment: Nope, Does not seem to help. The panel on refresh is closed.